# How can I prevent triggering a downstream project build in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, build, parameterized

We have a Jenkins setup where we have configured to trigger a nightly build on our super parent. We have configured our child projects with **Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built** parameter as true. This configuration works fine for our daily build requirement.
But the issue is whenever we build a Job manually, then also all child Jobs get triggered.
Is there a way so that I can restrict the triggering of downstream Job when I fire a manual build? Something like a parameterized build where If I set a parameter then downstream builds won't fire.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the **[Conditional BuildStep Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin)** which allows you to execute a downstream job based on certain conditions. Here is a screenshot :

[image]

As an example, you could do an *execute shell* which can evaluate a build parameter from the parent job and based on it you can trigger a downstream job.

Comment: Thanks DJ, but we don't want to hard code all the downstream projects. With our current config, whenever we add a new Job, the upstream and downstream projects are detected using its POM.
Is there any way by which it can automatically detect upstream-downstream projects?